# @ElementCollection not saved by Hibernate 4.0.1

Tags: spring-3, hibernate-4.x

I have class (entity) `A` which contains list of objects (entities) `B` which contains `Set<String> strings`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    private int id;
    private List<B> bList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "aId")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId", nullable = false)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    public List<B> getBList() {
        return bList;
    }
    ... setters and other stuff
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {

    private int id;
    private int aId;
    private Set<String> strings;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bId")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "b_strings", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bId")})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})**
    public Set<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    @Column(name = "aId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getAId() {
        return aId;
    }
    ... setters and other stuff
}
```

I create object `A` and then I try to save it:

```
A a = new A();
List<B> l = new ArrayList<B>();
a.setBList(l);
B b = new B();
l.add(b);
b.setStrings(new HashSet<String>());
b.getStrings().add("1");
b.getStrings().add("2");

b = new B();
l.add(b);
b.setStrings(new HashSet<String>());
b.getStrings().add("3");

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(a);
session.close();
```

`A` and `B` object is saved (inserted) but set with `strings` is not saved. I'm using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.0.1. Why is hibernate ignoring `@ElementCollection`? Table is created, mysql workbech shows it as readonly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapping is ok. I'm blind, session.beginTransaction(); and session.getTransaction().commit(); are missing, when saving object.